# can we send sms from cordys c3 to user directly?

Tags: web-services, soap, cordys-opentext

the scenario is : If certain transaction is done, then can we send message to the group of users involved in that transaction. Just like sms alert systems in java?? demos or references regarding it will be be appreciated . 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to send the message to multiple users. You can do that by sending the message to a role and it will be reaching the inbox of those people who has the role.